# python - turning a txt table into a 2D list

Tags: python, list, 2d

So I have a plate reader at work that will only output results into a plain text file like this

```
  1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10         
A   1.551   0.686   0.613   3.823   1.356   3.117   1.941   1.454   0.820   3.346   
B   3.811   3.403   3.782   3.811   3.474   3.811   3.811   3.811   0.396   0.378   
C   1.278   3.816   3.816   3.816   3.766   3.816   3.329   3.816   1.625   3.816  
D   1.354   1.689   1.182   3.819   3.819   1.241   1.099   2.826   1.780   2.018   
E   3.816   1.970   3.807   3.816   3.489   0.407   3.816   3.816   3.030   2.663   
F   3.622   1.080   0.846   0.574   3.169   2.313   1.113   1.166   1.567   1.983  
G   0.782   2.101   1.681   0.494   1.865   1.920   1.819   1.183   0.770   1.686  
H   2.561   1.046   2.009   2.410   0.751   3.814   2.703   0.799   1.935   3.814
```

and I am trying to write code that will read the floats from the table into a 2D list and then manipulate them. I can easily code the manipulation part but I am having trouble getting the data into the lists. The main problem is the 2 different variable types. Thus far I have:

```
import numpy as np
local = input ("enter the file location: ")
data = [np.array(map(int, line.split())) for line in open(local)]
```

Comment: Two different variable types? The first line is just indexes, which you would want to skip, and the first column is also not necessary.

Comment: Agree with @ThomasFenzl. You are trying to case your letters as int. Running your code I get this error: 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is close. The first line is just column indices, so you can skip it. The first column is row indices, also skippable. And your data is `float`, not `int`.

Also, use context managers to manage your resources, using the `with` statement, the file is closed automatically. Might not make a difference in a short script, but is a good habit to get into.

```
import numpy as np
local = input ("enter the file location: ")
with open(local) as f:
    f.readline()  #  skip column indices
    data = [np.array(map(float, line.split()[1:])) for line in f]
```